# Access values outside of async function and feed them to jquery keyframes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery to animate a div using variable data as input to the keyframes.

I have an `async function` that loop through a JSON file and parse each string every 1 second. The JSON consists of acceleration data.

I need to return these values to `function play(animation)`

I tried to globally initialize the variables, but I was only able to return one single value, but in my case, the values are coming every 1 second from the `async function`.

This is my data:

```
data=[
    {
        "time": 0,
        "accX": 0.11,
        "accZ": 0.11
    },
    {
        "time": 86400,
        "accX": 0.11,
        "accZ": 0.11
    },
    {
        "time": 172800,
        "accX": 0.11,
        "accZ": 0.11
    },
    {
        "time": 259200,
        "accX": 0.11,
        "accZ": 0.11
    }
]
```

this is the `async function`

```
var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
async function myLoop (data) {
      function retrieveAcceleration (obj) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          setTimeout(() => resolve({
            acceleration_x: obj.accX,
            acceleration_z: obj.accZ,
            timestamp: obj.time
          }), 1000)
        });
      }


      for (let ele of data) {
        keyframe = await retrieveAcceleration(ele);
        return keyframe
}
```

This is the function that animates the div

```
function play(animation) {
  myLoop (data)
  // how to access data from keyframe here?
  
    $('.track').resetKeyframe(function() {
        switch (animation) {
            case 'normal':
            $('.wheel').playKeyframe({
                name: 'wheelRotation',
                duration: "2000ms",
                timingFunction: 'linear',
                iterationCount: 'infinite'
              });
            break;
        }
        
    })
}
```

and I have a button that triggers this function when clicked

```
<input type="button" onclick="play('normal')" value="Start Motion" />
```

How to get the value from the keyframe without having to use console.log()? I am not able to access any value that is outside of the `async function`

Comment: `how to get the values from "keyframe"` you'll need to `await myLoop (data)` ... or `myLoop().then(() => ... in here ...)`

Comment: `the values are coming every 1 second from the async function` no, they come once after one second - your `for ... of` loop returns after the first await, because you `return keyframe`

Comment: Could you please provide an example of how this can be written. Much appreciated

Comment: No, because I don't even know how you call `play` and what the argument `animation` is used for, nor do I know where `data` even comes from that you send to `myLoop`

Comment: I edited the post, hope this is clearer

Comment: no, because you expect `myLoop` to *parse each string every 1 second.* and I have no clue how you could do that, maybe a generator

Comment: if I use console.log(keyframe) instead of return keyframe I get continuous values every 1 second, but when with return it only return one value when the function is called outside. While I understand what you meant. I there is another way to do it without asyn function? it is possible